# ionic 3 and local storage (retain the local storage values even after deployment)

Tags: ios, ionic3, local-storage

I am using ionic 3 to save user email id during login process using the following code.

```
localStorage.setItem('email_id', self.email);
```

Retrieve the same using

```
let shouldRemember = localStorage.getItem('shouldRemember');
```

Which works properly until i deploy a new version in App Store,
 the email ID value will get cleared, This problem occurs after new deployment to the app store.

How can i save the data so that even after the deployment i am able to get the value of the email ID.

Comment: try with JSON.stringify().

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest 2 things check which one works out for you.

**1.** Use following tag

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="img-src * 'self' data:; default-src * 'self' gap: ; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; ">
```

and make sure you access not as

```
var storage = window.localStorage;
```

but as

```
var storage = $window.localStorage;
```

as of IOS 10+ this should workout.

**2.** Instead of using localStorage I will suggest you to go with following plugin, [NativeStorage](https://github.com/TheCocoaProject/cordova-plugin-nativestorage)

As you know the main disadvantage of localStorage is that storage can be cleaned if OS requires space

Please refer [LocalStorageDocs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/9.x/cordova/storage/storage.html)